# Render iPhone 4 web app at 640x960 instead of 320x480?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

Our web app renders on the iPhone 4 at a resolution of 320x480, but we need to render it at 640x960.

We tried applying some of the StackOverflow recommendations for rendering native apps, but it didn't work.

For instance, we need a box to be 80 pixels wide on a 640x960 screen, but if we design the box using logical coordinates and give it 40 points, it only shows up as 40 pixels wide on the screen. And the whole screen is only 320 pixels wide instead of 640 pixels.

How can we render web apps using the full 640x960 resolution?

Comment: not necessarily--was just trying to understand your question better...

Comment: It cannot be done. The retina display always scales everything to 320x480 and there is nothing you can do about it.  Are you having issues with fuzzy images or something?  Why the need for such a resolution?

Comment: sgliser, could you post as answer? then we can credit you. we need the higher resolution because we want to put four avatars in a single row. at 80 pixels each, it's possible if the width is 640 but not at 320 (need to include space for margin and padding). the avatars won't work at 40 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a native web app in .net and all i did was in my css specified body{width:320px;}
not sure if that's what you are needing to do..